# smaller fonts for WP plug-in upPrev

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress plug-in [upPrev](https://wordpress.org/plugins/upprev-nytimes-style-next-post-jquery-animated-fly-in-button/screenshots/) which is quite useful.
I need to make fonts of the pop-up box smaller. i've already asked at the plugin's support forum but it's not active (pluging last update was 1 year ago).

There is a custom css section with the following code that i assume that you can change, can you please assist ?

```
/* header */
#upprev_box h6 a { }
/* header link: mouse over */
#upprev_box h6 a:hover { }
/* headera link: visited */
#upprev_box h6 a:visited { }
/* container for title, thumbnail and excerpt */
#upprev_box .upprev_excerpt { }
/* excerpt */
#upprev_box .upprev_excerpt p { }
/* previous post link */
#upprev_box .upprev_excerpt p a { }
/* previous post link: mouse over */
#upprev_box .upprev_excerpt p a:hover { }
/* previous post link: visited */
#upprev_box .upprev_excerpt p a:visited { }
/* thumbnail image */
#upprev_box .upprev_thumb { }
/* close button */
#upprev_close { }
```

Comment: Inspect the font with your browsers developer tools. There should be displayed where the current size is defined or which class you could use to change it.

Comment: You can use original plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/upprev/ this one, which you use is just a copy of mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about the plugin but by seeing the selectors you added I presume that you can add your new font-size in:

```
#upprev_box .upprev_excerpt p
```

and

```
#upprev_box h6 a
```

this will probably solve the problem at least for the title and description

Comment: thanks for your feedback,
i've changed 

    #upprev_box h6 a:hover { } --> #upprev_box xx-small a:hover { } 

    #upprev_box h6 a:visited { } --> #upprev_box xx-small a:visited { }

without any success
i've also removed the # from the start of each line but didn't have any change.

Comment: Can you share some html code so I can help you better?

Comment: please check here http://www.natural-ice.gr/%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%8A%CF%8C%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1/
if you scroll down you will see the popup with the Hello world in the right

Comment: There are 2 headings in your popup, to specify the first one you need to use `#upprev_box h6` selector and for the bigger red one you need `#upprev_box div.upprev_thumbnail h5 a` selector. I guess you can add them in your custom css file as it's going to be used globally from the plugin.